# Ansible 'aws_secret ' lookup variable

Tags: ansible, aws-secrets-manager

Team,

Am trying to variablize all the parameter part of the aws_secret plugin. But not able to assign variable for the region. Have tried something like `'{{ aws_secret_region }}'` , `'"{{ aws_secret_region }}"'`, it's throwing error as Provided region_name `'{{aws_secret_region}}'` doesn't match a supported format.". When trying to pass the region as the environment variable or arg, it's throwing ```You must specify a region`` error Any suggestions?

Code :

```
   hosts: localhost
  vars:
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
        db_password: "{{ lookup('aws_secret', '{{ aws_secret_name }}', region='us-east-1') | from_json | json_query('\"' + aws_secret_key + '\"') }}"
```

Error (when passing the region as env var):

```
fatal: [10.1.24.158]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ lookup('aws_secret', '{{ aws_secret_name }}') | from_json | json_query('\"' + aws_secret_key + '\"') }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'aws_secret'. Error was a <class 'botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError'>, original message: You must specify a region."}
```

Comment: You cannot use jinja2 expansion when already inside a jinja2 expansion. Simply use the var name => `db_password: "{{ lookup('aws_secret', aws_secret_name, region=aws_secret_region) }}"

Comment: @Zeitounator Thats worked, Thank you . ``` db_password: "{{ lookup('aws_secret', aws_secret_name, region=aws_secret_region) | from_json | json_query('\"' + aws_secret_key + '\"') }}"```